# Como ler uma coluna 'boolean' usando NPGSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Tenho o seguinte código no evento *Validated* de um TextBox:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(
    "Server=127.0.0.1; port=5432;User; Id=postgres; Password=572600;Database=Sistema");

conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"
        SELECT * FROM usuario 
        WHERE codigo_usuario=" + textBox1.Text, conn);
NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    textBox2.Text = dr["nome"].ToString();
    //   checkBox1.Checked = dr["inativo"];
    textBox3.Text = dr["senha"].ToString();
    radioButton1.Text = dr["nivel"].ToString();
           
    conn.Close();
}
```

O campo "inativo" no banco de dados é boolean e eu gostaria que retornasse o CheckBox de acordo com true ou false que estiver no registro do banco de dados.

Comment: O que acontece, provavelmente, é o que o valor de dr["inativo"], não seja uma variável booleana, apesar desse campo, no banco, ser. Tente o seguinte: veja, por debug, o valor de dr["inativo"]. Se o valor for, por exemplo, "True", faça: checkBox1.Checked = String.Equals(dr["inativo"].ToString(), "True");

Comment: João Victor Sierra é isso mesmo que eu precisava muito obrigado pela ajuda sou iniciante em C#

Caso eu precisa converter um campo String da banco de dados, se for true o radiobutton1 fica checked, se for falseu radiobutton2 fica checked , como faço ?
 radioButton1.Text = dr["nivel"].ToString(); seria isso ?

Comment: A resposta solucionou seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Se o campo no PG realmente é um *booleano*, use `Convert.ToBoolean`

```
checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["inativo"]);
```